# I'm having trouble calling up a value inside a class

Tags: python, class, mouseevent

I'm having trouble calling up this value within the class and I don't understand what might be wrong with this implementation

```
class imageClick:
    def image_clicked(self,event):
        self.x = event.x
        self.y = event.y

userClick = imageClick()
print userClick.image_clicked.x
```

Comment: I tried doing that, but it gave me this error: AttributeError: imageClick instance has no attribute 'x'

Comment: because you are not passing `event` in `imageClick()`

Comment: More specifically, you're never *calling* `image_clicked()`.

Comment: check [this code](http://codepad.org/F1pDhIB4)

Comment: What, exactly, in your own words, were you expecting the `x` value to be, and why? Where does the information come from?

Comment: I was expecting the x to be the x_coordinate of the mouse click.

Comment: I was assuming that the information would be provided from the Tkinter widget. The problem that I'm having now is calling the function, but since event seems to be declared only with the event function - 'image_clicked', I'm struggling with how to call event outside of the event function in order to call information from within the class.

Answer (score 4):

The `imageClick` class should have an initializer method to declare the attributes in the first place:

```
class imageClick:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None
    def image_clicked(self, event):
        self.x = event.x
        self.y = event.y
```

Now try this:

```
userClick = imageClick()
userClick.image_clicked(someEvent)
print userClick.x
```

Notice that `imageClick`'s `image_clicked()` method expects an event as a parameter - and that's where the `x` and `y` coordinates are obtained from.

Comment: I'm new to this and I assumed that event could only be used in 'def image_clicked(self, event)'. How would you use event outside the event function. Thanks for you help so far. Your answer is amazing.

Comment: @Dta I guess that you have an `Event` class (or why are you passing an event in the first place?) . So somewhere in your code you must create a new object, like this: `someEvent = Event()` and that's the one that gets passed to `image_clicked()`. It really depends on how you're writing the rest of the program, it's impossible to tell without seeing all the code.